# Create mulitple csv automatically from different select statements & save in a given path

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I have a stored procedure to return csv output in a path after the query executes. But it only works for a single csv.

I want a script to generate multiple csv together from multiple SQL statements and store in a path.

My input is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA8Ob.jpg)

```
---------------------------------------------
--- Generating output csv by stored procedure
---------------------------------------------

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * from #TMP_Lazyone_All_Final'
DECLARE @file_path NVARCHAR(4000) = N'D:\a\Lazyone_ComplexProducts_Final.csv' -- Change filename path
DECLARE @Status INT = 1

EXECUTE spa_util_GetCsv  @DBFetch = @sql,               
                @Header = 1,
                @PCWrite = @file_path,
                @HeaderQuote = 0,
                @Status = @Status OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop to achieve what you need:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    id int,
    querys nvarchar(max),
    filename nvarchar(max)
)

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @file_path NVARCHAR(4000) = N'D:\a\',
        @Status INT = 1

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(0, 'first query', @file_path+'first'+'.csv'),
(1, 'second query',@file_path+ 'second'+'.csv')
--etc

WHILE @i < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t)
BEGIN
    SELECT  @sql = querys,
            @file_path = filename
    FROM @t
    WHERE id = @i


    EXECUTE spa_util_GetCsv  @DBFetch = @sql,               
                    @Header = 1,
                    @PCWrite = @file_path,
                    @HeaderQuote = 0,
                    @Status = @Status OUTPUT  
    SET @i=@i+1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Shell Script as below.

```
$categories = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance SERVERINSTANCENAME -Database DATABASENAME -Query "use yourDBName;select categories from yourtable;"
  foreach($category in $categories){
     $categoryName = $category.name
     $attachmentFilePath = "D:\$categoryName.csv"
     $QueryFmt = "Select * from yourtable where categories=$categoryName"
     Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance SERVERINSTANCENAME -Database DATABASENAME  -Query $QueryFmt | Export-CSV $attachmentFilePath
  }
```